# How return list from one class to other class

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want return list to other class->method

I have method in one class

```
public static List<StatsList> GetAdsStats(string Ticket, DateTime start, DateTime end, int CamId)
    {
        var client = new CampaignStatsServiceClient();
        var id = new CampaignIdFilter();
        id.CampaignId = CamId;
        var statsdata = new GetAdStatsData();
        var kazkas = new Campaign();
        kazkas = client.GetAdStats(Ticket, new GetAdStatsData
        {
            IdFilter = id,
            StartDate = start,
            EndDate = end
        });

        int reklamos = kazkas.Ads.Length;
        long[] statistikaClikai = new long[reklamos];
        long[] statistikaImpresions = new long[reklamos];

                                    List<StatsList> items = new List<StatsList>();
        for (int i = 0; i < reklamos; i++)
        {
             long AllClicks = 0;
             long AllImpresions = 0;

            int dienos = kazkas.Ads[i].Days.Length;
            for (int lop = 0; lop < dienos; lop++)
            {

                AllClicks = AllClicks + kazkas.Ads[i].Days[lop].Stats.Clicks;
                AllImpresions = AllImpresions + kazkas.Ads[i].Days[lop].Stats.Impressions;
            }
            items.Add(new StatsList() { ID =kazkas.Ads[i].Id, clicks = AllClicks , impresions = AllImpresions });

        }
        return items;
    }
```

And I want return list to other class->method and show it to web (list)

```
public ActionResult GetStats()
        {
            int Ids = 141611;
            DateTime start = new DateTime(2013, 05, 29);
            DateTime end = new DateTime(2013, 06, 17);
            GetAdStatsService GetAdStatsService = new GetAdStatsService();        
            return View();
        }
```

In first method, I find everything is working fine, but in second, I didn't know how to get list correctly, please help

Comment: call `<ClassName>.GetAdStats(ticket, start, end, id)` from the other method? Or make the method non-static

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `GetAdsStats` is static - no need to create an instance of `GetAdStatsService`:

```
List<ApiClient.GetAdStatsService.StatsList> items = GetAdStatsService.GetAdsStats("ticket string argument", start, end, Ids);
```

Comment: your method didin't work. error says
Error 4 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<ApiClient.GetAdStatsService.StatsList>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<OptimizingAds.Models.StatsList>' C:\Users\vartotojas\Desktop\Academy.OptimizingAds-master\Academy.OptimizingAds-master\OptimizingAds\OptimizingAds\OptimizingAds\Controllers\HomeController.cs 58 37 OptimizingAds

Comment: @sparagas, you have several `StatsList` classes declared. Adjusted class name accordingly, see updated version.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your code at the top belongs to `GetAdStatsService` you have to do

```
return View(
 GetAdStatsService.GetAdsStats(
    "" /*ticket is missed, not sure what to pass*/,
    start,
    end,
    Ids) 
);
```

And remove this line as it's not necessary taking into account that `GetAdsStats` is static

```
GetAdStatsService GetAdStatsService = new GetAdStatsService();
```

A sample of how to use the model on the view would be

```
@model IList<HereGoesTheNamespace.StatsList>
...
//Use your model here at will
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.clicks)
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.impresions)
```

Comment: and how .html file should looks like?

Comment: @sparagas: added some code for the view, but it's just a reference and I don't know what you need to do

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `GetAdStats` is a function of the `GetAdStatsService` object, you would get the items from the method by calling the following I presume:

`GetAdStatsService.GetAdStats(string Ticket, DateTime start, DateTime end, int CamId)`